# Windows 7 update failed, can't boot, can't restore

Tags: windows-7, boot, multi-boot, system-restore

System is a Lenovo ThinkPad T530 laptop, i5 proc 16 GB RAM 256GB SSD, 500GB HDD, nVidia 5400 gpu, set up to dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu Linux since I got it back in fall 2012 or so.

Everything has been more or less happily co-existing so far.  Re-booted into Windows for the occasional game or some domain-specific programs that don't work well in a VM.

This morning I rebooted, wanting to spend some quality time on Steam ;)  and noticed that I had some updates due in avast!, and in Windows as well.  Applied the updates, initiated the reboot, and left to go do something else, as there were 25+ system updates that needed applied.

When I got back, it had rebooted up to the Ubuntu login screen, as per my default.  I did a shutdown/reboot so I could get back to Windows.

It came up with a CLI screen prompt about whether I wanted to do a Startup Recovery, or Boot Normally.  I opted to boot normally, and see WTF was going on here.

It got about 5 seconds into the Windows splash screen - it just started to display the Windows logo at the bottom center of the screen, flashed to a BSOD for about half a second, and was back to the BIOS boot screen again.

After navigating back to the same screen, I selected Startup Recovery, and worked my way thru that.  No luck - said it couldn't complete.  Attempted a System Restore - which only gave one restore point, the one from right before the reboot - because of course, when I did some house-cleaning the last time I was booted into Windows, one of the things I cleared out to make some room was.... the old system restore points.  Didn't think I got rid of *all* of them, though.

Anyway, the System Restore failed as well.  So now I'm sitting here with a failed Windows 7 install, that I can't boot into, I can't restore... and my last Windows disk image was a while ago - if I can find it (got lazy, as my Linux use increased and its usually quicker to blow those away, reinstall the system and restore the user files from backup).

Any suggestions on how to get my Windows 7 partition working again?

Comment: You don't have a lot of options.  System Restore was basically it.

Comment: Well, things may be going down-hill fast... started getting some GRUB (linux boot loader) error messages during reboot... now I'm wondering if the SSD is packing it in...

Comment: Backup the drive, perform no writes, if the SSD has failed that your best chance to recover your data

Comment: Question... if the drive is already corrupted... how much of the data is likely to be salvageable?  I'm currently backing up my (linux) user files to a NAS, and once that is done will be backing up some other important things (virtual machines that can't easily be replaced) to an external USB 3.0 drive, and then doing a disk image using clonezilla... so I *should* be covered...

Comment: Only way to find how much is to try